# Android Web Services Client (JSON)

Tags: java, android, xml, json, web-services

I am working on an android app, This app is a client for a web service running in glassfish 3.1.2.2, this web services work with xml and json parser's, i test externally de WS to view the answer what I get and when I looked for a xml answer from the server i get the xml data, and same happened with Json answer.

**Problem**

Problem come with the android client in the get method in which I set the content-type as application/json, but WS only response xml.

Could anyone tell me where i am doing wrong, i will put the code and log in the end.

**Code:-**

```
private class TareaWSObtener extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

        //CONSTANTES
        private static final String CONTENT = "Content-Type"; //content-type
        private static final String JSONTYPE = "application/json"; //application/json
        private static final String LOGWS = "MovilSecure:WebServices";
        private int id;
        private String nombre;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean result = true;

            Log.i(LOGWS, "Levantando cliente");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8080/WS-MovilSecure_SandBox_ONLY_/webresources/persona");
            //get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            Log.i(LOGWS, "cliente levantado");
            try{
                Log.i(LOGWS, "Obteniendo data");
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(get);

                String stringRsp = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                JSONObject respJSON = new JSONObject(stringRsp);

                id = respJSON.getInt("idPersona");
                nombre = respJSON.getString("nombre");
                Log.i(LOGWS, "Data Obtenida");

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(LOGWS, "Problemas al conectar con el WS", e);
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(boolean result){
            if(result){Log.i(LOGWS, "data:"+id+nombre);}
        }

    }
```

**Log:-**

```
09-13 21:52:50.073: I/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155): Levantando cliente
09-13 21:52:50.123: I/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155): cliente levantado
09-13 21:52:50.123: I/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155): Obteniendo data
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155): Problemas al conectar con el WS
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155): org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml       of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at com.example.wsclient_movilesecure.MainActivity$TareaWSObtener.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:110)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at com.example.wsclient_movilesecure.MainActivity$TareaWSObtener.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-13 21:52:50.293: E/MovilSecure:WebServices(3155):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: What about `Accept` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the Accept header. You can read about it here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

"The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response."

```
get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

The **Content-Type** header is used to indicate what type of data you are sending. In the case of a GET request, your request has no body. You do not need to set **Content-Type** in this case.

Comment: Thank you you are right, i did not know that about the headers i will investigate a little more, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this an error but try to uncomment this line

```
 //get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to use robospice library for this. I did the same way like you to consume server resources and this is inconsistent, bad response when you use 3g or if you turn your smarthphone or tablet this crush your app.

Anyways here is my code with a simple sample:

(This is a good practices, 3 intents and close the connection if you end)

```
    boolean ok = false;
     String insertar = "http://www.SuperCalifragi.net/api/Registro/Registro";
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
            {
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                 try {
                    URL url = new URL(insertar);
                    connection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String input = gson.toJson(user,RegistroUsuarioViewModel.class);      
                    System.out.println("enviamos: "+input);

                    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();             
                    os.write(input.getBytes());
                    os.flush();

                    String response = "";  
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {  
                      response = "Error From Server \n\n";  
                    } else {  
                      response = "Response From Server \n\n";  
                    }   
                    System.out.println("responsee: "+response + " - "+connection.getResponseCode());
                    BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));

                    String output ="";
                    while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        resultadoRegistro = resultadoRegistro + output;
                    }            
                    con = gson.fromJson(resultadoRegistro, Conexion.class);
                    System.out.println("CONTENIDO: "+con);
                    ok = true;
                } catch(SocketTimeoutException e){

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                } catch(Exception e){           
                }finally{
                    if( i > 3 && connection != null){
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }if(ok){
                     i = 10; //break loop
                     connection.disconnect();
                   }

                }
            }
```